# How would one get out of a Question and Answer ban?

Tags: discussion, answers, post-ban

Although I personally am not in this situation, I was wondering if it was even possible to get out of a ban if you were banned from both asking and answering. Would you just try to edit your answers and questions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Would you just try to edit your answers and questions?

Yes. With the constraint that the edited result should still be relevant (say a question - if it has answers, they should still be valid answers to the edited question). Of course, the idea is to *improve* the posts, not just edit them.

One additional thing to do is offer suggested edits on other posts, though this could be a very slow way to get out of the ban it is better than nothing at all (especially if your edited posts are not getting much attention).

---

The above can take time. A long time. So patience is required. If there are no posts one can improve, and it has been weeks and months since participating positively on the site, you can use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form and as the Community Team for intervention. This is not guaranteed to work.

The fact is, if someone managed to get into both bans, in particular since [rolling bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide/243469#243469) were introduced, they are simply not paying attention or learning. And we may very well be better off without them.